# Scraping website, why does code give different result?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

Why when I click the website and saw the website source code, it gives me an organized result.

All I want is the date, teams and scores.

This is my Python code:

```
import requests, bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get("https://www.scoreboard.com/mls/results/")
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")
print(soup.prettify())
```

Here is the result when I search "Los Angeles". My code returned:

[image]

But when I open the source code of website: https://www.scoreboard.com/mls/results/
it tells me:

[image]

I don't know why the Python result is totally different.

Answer (score 1):

This site uses its own feed syntax, it seems that they use ~ as row separator, ¬ for object separator, and ÷ for key/value. So the following :

> SA÷1¬~ZA÷USA:
>   MLS¬ZEE÷CQv5qrFt¬ZB÷200¬ZY÷USA¬ZC÷zRdKgb4m¬ZD÷t¬ZE÷KM2qHMND¬ZF÷0¬ZO÷0¬ZG÷1¬ZH÷200_CQv5qrFt¬ZJ÷2¬ZL÷/mls/¬ZX÷04USA
>   003......0000000000179000MLS         003......000¬ZS÷2018¬ZCC÷0¬ZAF÷USA¬~AA÷bTyQbGCR¬AD÷1528943400¬ADE÷1528943400¬AB÷3¬CR÷3¬AC÷3¬CX÷San
>   Jose Earthquakes¬RW÷0¬AX÷1¬BX÷-1¬HMC÷1¬WQ÷¬WM÷JOS¬AE÷San Jose
>   Earthquakes¬JA÷Ms72iE3l¬WU÷san-jose-earthquakes¬AS÷0¬AZ÷0¬AG÷2¬BA÷1¬BC÷1¬WN÷ENG¬AF÷New
>   England
>   Revolution¬JB÷G466jYIf¬WV÷new-england-revolution¬AS÷0¬AZ÷0¬AH÷2¬BB÷2¬BD÷0¬AW÷1¬

becomes this in json format (a JSON object represents a single row here) :

```
{
    "SA" : "1",
},
{
    "ZA": "USA : MLS",
    "ZEE": "CQv5qrFt",
    "ZB": "200",
    "ZY": "USA",
    "ZC": "zRdKgb4m",
    "ZD": "t",
    "ZE": "KM2qHMND",
    "ZF": "0",
    "ZO": "0",
    "ZG": "1",
    "ZH": "200_CQv5qrFt",
    "ZJ": "2",
    "ZL": "/mls/",
    "ZX": "04USA         003......0000000000179000MLS         003......000",
    "ZS": "2018",
    "ZCC": "0",
    "ZAF": "USA"
}
```

If you look at https://www.scoreboard.com/x/js/core_500_1495000000.js it contains minified code, just replace `eval` with `console.log` here to print the whole code and find the key name such as ZEE, ZA, ZD etc... You'll come up with something like this :

```
{
    "sportId" : "1",
},
{
    "tournamentName": "USA : MLS",
    "tournamentTemplateId": "CQv5qrFt",
    "countryId": "200",
    "countryName": "USA",
    "tournamentStageId": "zRdKgb4m",
    "tournamentType": "t",
    "tournamentId": "KM2qHMND",
    "sourceType": "0",
    "hasLiveTable": "0",
    "statsType": "1",
    "tournamentTemplateKey": "200_CQv5qrFt",
    "tournamentStageType": "2",
    "tournamentTemplateUrl": "/mls/",
    "sortKey": "04USA         003......0000000000179000MLS         003......000",
    "seasonUrl": "2018",
    "stagesCount": "0",
    "categoryCaption": "USA"
}
```

It's for the tournament description, the following rows describes all the items in the table, example for one row :

```
{
    "eventId": "GOSl9rMa",
    "matchStartUtime": "1528938000",
    "eventStartUtime": "1528938000",
    "eventStageTypeId": "3",
    "eventStageTypeFromEventStageId": "3",
    "eventStageId": "3",
    "sortParticipant": "Colorado Rapids",
    "cricketVisibleRunRate": "0",
    "hasLineups": "1",
    "gameTime": "-1",
    "hasMatchComments": "1",
    "cricketRecentOvers": "",
    "home3CharName": "COL",
    "homeParticipantName": "Colorado Rapids",
    "eventParticipantId": "2BPTi8xM",
    "participantNameUrl": "colorado-rapids",
    "winner": "0",
    "ftWinner": "0",
    "homeCurrentResult": "2",
    "homeResultPeriod1": "2",
    "homeResultPeriod2": "0",
    "away3CharName": "CHI",
    "awayParticipantName": "Chicago Fire",
    "awayParticipantId": "t2OXjSiS",
    "awayParticipantNameUrl": "chicago-fire",
    "winner": "0",
    "ftWinner": "0",
    "awayRedCardCount": "1",
    "awayCurrentResult": "2",
    "awayResultPeriod1": "2",
    "awayResultPeriod2": "0",
    "hasLiveCenter": "1"
}
```

Note that multiple same keys can be present in this format (not strict analogy with json in this case)

Answer (score 0):

```
requests.get(url)
```

This code will post a http request to url, and webserver will return the website source code.If you click `CTRL + U` in Chrome, the source will be same with your result from python scraping.

The different result your asked is that the data will be loaded after website loaded, it will be loaded by webiste's javascript. In other word, data your wanted is loaded by Ajax.

You can Open Chrome -> `F12` -> `Network` -> `XHR` -> Refresh your website want to scrape.

Notice the log from Chrome. You can get Ajax data in general by this way. Sometimes you should convert format.

like your website, I find two address to get Ajax data：

- `https://www.scoreboard.com/x/feed/mc_8`
- `https://d.scoreboard.com/x/feed/tr_1_200_CQv5qrFt_155_1_8_en-usa_1`

But you need to do something like converting format according to the corresponding js code.